# How to remove new line from text file in for loop (CMD/Batch)

Tags: batch-file, cmd

My goal is to use a text file created by a for loop as an input for a variable to another for loop. However, the initial text file created has a new line/space at the end, and is being declared as a variable when reading said text file.

Code below is creating a text file...

```
for /F "Skip=1 Delims=:" %%A In ('WMIC LogicalDisk Get Caption') do @echo(%%A>> "EXAMPLE DIRECTORY\partitions.txt"
```

This text output file then looks like

```
A
C
D
(empty line)
```

I am then using this text file to feed into another for command for which each of these lines are used as a variable.

```
for /F "delims=" %%P in (EXAMPLE DIRECTORY\partitions.txt) do (echo test.exe -partition %%P
```

This (empty line) or space is being fed as a variable and it is undesirable so I am looking for a fix somewhere along this chain of commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have simply asked in the topic I provided the answer to you.

```bat
(For /F "Skip=1 Delims=:" %%A In ('WMIC LogicalDisk Get Caption') Do For %%B In (%%A) Do Echo(%%B:)>"EXAMPLE DIRECTORY\partitions.txt"
```

Comment: Thank you for responding again. Sorry I do not use Stackoverflow much and didn't know protocol for asking questions within again. However the above code did not end up taking away that newline character saved to the text file. Instead I had to do a manual test in the second code to for loop through a list of A-Z characters and do only run the command if that variable was equal to any of those letters.

Answer (score 2):

Don't include non needed lines in the output file

```dos
>"EXAMPLE DIRECTORY\partitions.txt" (
    for /f "tokens=2 delims==:" %%a in ('
        wmic logicaldisk get caption /value
    ') do (echo(%%a)
)
```

Asking `wmic` for the `/value` format the output will be like

```
Caption=C:
```

Using the colon and the equal sign as delimiters we only leave the drive letter and, as we are requesting `tokens=2`, lines without a second token (the drive letter) are discarded.